# In Visual Studio 2010 Folder Difference window, when I right click on file the "Reconcile" menu is disabled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, directory, file-comparison, filecompare

I'm trying to compare 2 local folders. In source control explorer I right click folder, click "Compare" menu and select the target folder.
The Folder Difference folder is displayed.
I right click the file where the difference is found but the "Reconcile" menu is disabled.
I have both "Read" and "Check Out" permissions on both source and target folders.

Comment: Are you specifying a local path or a server path for the target folder?

Comment: I'm comparing two local folders.

Answer (score 0):

Reconcile will not work with two local paths.  It is instead used to update the changes made locally with changes on the server.  It will allows you to pend server changes based on the contents of your locally mapped paths.  This is the reconcile dialog:

[image]

You can thus synchronize your local tree (or a part of it) with the server from within the Compare window, which allows you fine-grained control of which files to download or which files to pend changes on.  This is useful if you wanted to only get latest on certain files that had been updated on the server.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've misread the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385984.aspx

Comment: After you compare a **server folder and a local folder**, you can reconcile the differences between the folder contents and between files that have conflicting pending changes in your local folder.